# Stylesheet doesn't load in Firfefox/IE/Opera, works fine in Chrome, Mobile Safari, Safari (desktop)

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, stylesheet

The Page I've designed works perfectly in Chrome and Safari but doesn't work in other browsers

Link: http://intelsystems.in/testing/

Comment: Why do you have a space in `</scri pt>` while including the js.flexslider.js ?

Comment: Check your HTML, its not correct you have got doctype tag in body element and other meta tags inside body which should be in head tag. Also you need to define doctype before html tag.

Comment: ... and 34 other errors. And many warnings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this rule in your theme CSS:

```
.plus .theHoverBorder:hover{
    background-image:url(../img/plus01.png
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-color:rgba(35,35,35,0.5)
}
```

Note the lack of a closing `);` on the background-image.  Per spec, this makes the `}` get ignored and that makes all the following rules get ignored.

WebKit has a number of CSS parsing bugs, and this is hitting one of them: they are not following the spec here, which is why this "works" in Chrome and Safari.  The other browsers are following the spec.